# Getting gcc error when launching terminal

Tags: ubuntu, gcc, terminal

I get `gcc: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--showme:link’` when I first open the terminal. Why?

Comment: Because *something* is invoking `gcc` with `--showme:link` as a command-line argument. Check your startup files (`.bashrc`, `bash_profile`, etc.).

Comment: @KeithThompson: `bash_profile` is empty and I searched for keywords `gcc` and `showme` in `bashrc`  but could not find those.

Comment: http://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam-installation/97581-showme-errors.html

Comment: @KeithThompson: Removing the line related to openfoam in `bashrc` solved the problem. thx!